# Mersenne number with small Carmichael function

Tags: prime-numbers, arithmetic-functions

Let $\lambda(\cdot)$ be the [Carmichael function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carmichael_function). I'm trying to understand the magnitude of the smallest values of $\lambda(2^n - 1)$, when $n$ runs over the positive integers. Precisely my question is:

> Can we prove that $\lambda(2^n - 1) \ll 2^{o(n)}$ for infinitely many
>   positive integers $n$?

Thanks for any advice/reference.

Comment: There might be something in Kazimierz Szymiczek, On the distribution of prime factors of Mersenne numbers, Prace Mat. 13 (1969) 33–49, MR0252316 (40 #5537).

Comment: @GerryMyerson It might be, but I didn't found that paper anywhere.

Comment: Can you provide a table of values?  I do not have a lambda routine handy.  Gerhard "Nor A Sheepda Routine Either" Paseman, 2017.06.06.

Comment: @GerhardPaseman Here https://jpst.it/-jHl you find all pairs $n, \; \lambda(2^n -  1)$ for $n=1,\ldots,100$

Comment: The Szymiczek paper is available at https://wydawnictwa.ptm.org.pl/index.php/commentationes-mathematicae/article/download/5654/5195